# Simple singleton database connection pool

Tags: java, design-patterns, database, singleton, connection-pool

I'm studying design patterns, and to demonstrate a singleton, I've implemented a primitive database connection pool.

**ConnectionPool.java**

```
package com.levent.connpool;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConnectionPool {

    private final static int MAX_CONNECTIONS = 8;
    private static ConnectionPool instance = null;  // lazy loading
    private static Connection[] connections = new Connection[MAX_CONNECTIONS];
    private static String dbUrl = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/memory:levoDB/singletonDemo;create=true";
    private static int counter;

    private ConnectionPool() { }

    public static ConnectionPool getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) {
            synchronized(ConnectionPool.class) {
                if(instance == null) {
                    instance = new ConnectionPool();
                    initializeConnections();
                    counter = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        return instance;
    }

    private static void initializeConnections() {
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_CONNECTIONS; i++) {
            try {
                connections[i] = DriverManager.getConnection(dbUrl);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        counter++;
        if(counter == Integer.MAX_VALUE)
            counter = 0;

        return connections[counter%MAX_CONNECTIONS];
    }

}
```

**ConnectionPoolDemo.java**

```
package com.levent.connpool;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConnectionPoolDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConnectionPool pool = ConnectionPool.getInstance();

        Connection[] connections = new Connection[17];

        for(int i = 0; i < connections.length; i++)
            connections[i] = pool.getConnection();

        int preIndex = connections[0].getClass().getCanonicalName().length();
        for(int i = 0; i < connections.length; i++)
            System.out.printf("Connection %2d : %s\n", i+1, connections[i].toString().substring(preIndex));

        for(int i = 0; i < connections.length; i++)
            try {
                connections[i].close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

}
```

The output is as follows:

> ```
> Connection  1 : @27f8302d
> Connection  2 : @6438a396
> Connection  3 : @e2144e4
> Connection  4 : @6477463f
> Connection  5 : @3d71d552
> Connection  6 : @1cf4f579
> Connection  7 : @18769467
> Connection  8 : @46ee7fe8
> Connection  9 : @27f8302d
> Connection 10 : @6438a396
> Connection 11 : @e2144e4
> Connection 12 : @6477463f
> Connection 13 : @3d71d552
> Connection 14 : @1cf4f579
> Connection 15 : @18769467
> Connection 16 : @46ee7fe8
> Connection 17 : @27f8302d
> ```

**Explanation**

The aims is to have distributed connections that's why on each `getConnection()` method call, on of the each connections are returned with the use of mod. The maximum connection size is determined by the `MAX_CONNECTIONS` which is set to 8 in this example and all 17 connections retrieved from the singleton pool class are recurring instances of the 8 connections stored in the `ConnectionPool` class.

I know that this code is not a big shot, but my aim was to demonstrate a simple singleton in a real world example. I'm waiting for your ideas and your criticism.

Answer (score 4):

1. Your connection pool is not threadsafe / concurrently usable, if you are sure you do not need it to be ignore my points 1. to 3.
2. Your pool does not offer connection locking (mutual exclusive usage of one Connection object) which is usually implemented by making the connection inaccessible after getConnection() and making it eligible for takeout after calling its close() method. You close the raw connections manually, leaving the pool in a broken state.
   This is problematic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428573/
3. Your counter int might return the same int for two concurrent calls at the same time. Use AtomicInteger / AtomicLong instead.
4. Your pool does not implement connection testing: Your connections could expire at any time. You need to replace broken Connections with new Connections or your program might receive dead Connection objects!
5. You might want to implement Closeable to close all connections at once when your application shuts down and clear the instance.
6. You might want to throw if initializeConnections fails, because what are you supposed to do with a broken object?
7. Hardcoding URLs that might change is not considered good practice

Answer (score 1):

A more defensive implementation of creating a singleton is known as the [`enum` singleton pattern](https://www.google.com/search?q=enum+singleton+java) (I can't really find a definitive source, hence the copping-out with a Google search link). That means instead of rolling your own `public class` (which really should be a `public final class` so that nothing else can sub-class it), you use an `enum`:

```
public enum ConnectionPool {
    INSTANCE;

    // some internal fields here

    private ConnectionPool() {
        // do required initialization here
    }

    public static ConnectionPool getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

You may also want to look into standardizing your braces approach for all code blocks, including one-liners. This will make the scoping more apparent.

Comment: I've just noticed this useful answer, I'll take a look up to enum singleton pattern. Thanks for your useful comment.

Comment: But how do you pass the connection params. for a less likely command line application that takes connection params from stdin

Comment: @SomasundaramSekar I'll suggest you can put that as a new question over here on Code Review. :)