# Composite implementation of a prototype singleton registry

Tags: java, object-oriented, design-patterns, singleton

I am studying design patterns and I've implemented a composite prototype pattern which is also a singleton (one instance per JVM). The main and most important part of the code is the `Registry class` which is a singleton.

The `Movie` and `Book` classes are inherited from the abstract `Item` class which implements the `Cloneable` interface of Java. I haven't changed the default `cloneable()` method to make a shallow copy of the `Item` objects whenever they are cloned. I'm not sure If it is better to choose a deep copy implementation in this simple example.

The responsibility of the Registry class is:

1. Store the items prototypes in a map
2. Create items with cloning the stored prototypes

**`Item` class**

```
package com.levent.prototype;

public abstract class Item implements Cloneable {

    // fields
    private long itemId;
    private String itemTitle;
    private ItemStatus itemStatus;

    // inner static enum
    public static enum ItemStatus {
        AVAILABLE,
        SOLD
    }

    // argument constructor
    public Item(long itemId, String itemTitle, ItemStatus itemStatus) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
        this.itemTitle = itemTitle;
        this.itemStatus = itemStatus;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        // returns a shallow copy of the Item or subclass objectss
        // Should implement a deep copy instead ?
        return super.clone();
    }

    // getters & setters
    public long getItemId() {
        return itemId;
    }

    public void setItemId(long itemId) {
        this.itemId = itemId;
    }

    public String getItemTitle() {
        return itemTitle;
    }

    public void setItemTitle(String itemTitle) {
        this.itemTitle = itemTitle;
    }

    public ItemStatus getItemStatus() {
        return itemStatus;
    }

    public void setItemStatus(ItemStatus itemStatus) {
        this.itemStatus = itemStatus;
    }
}
```

**`Movie` class**

```
package com.levent.prototype;

public class Movie extends Item {

    // fields
    private int duration;
    private String director;

    // argument constructor
    public Movie(long itemId, String itemTitle, ItemStatus itemStatus, int duration, String director) {
        super(itemId, itemTitle, itemStatus);
        this.duration = duration;
        this.director = director;
    }

    // getters & setters
    public int getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(int duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public String getDirector() {
        return director;
    }

    public void setDirector(String director) {
        this.director = director;
    }

}
```

**`Book` class**

```
package com.levent.prototype;

public class Book extends Item {

    // fields
    private int numberOfPages;
    private String author;

    // argument constructor
    public Book(long itemId, String itemTitle, ItemStatus itemStatus, int numberOfPages, String author) {
        super(itemId, itemTitle, itemStatus);
        this.numberOfPages = numberOfPages;
        this.author = author;
    }

    // getters & setters
    public int getNumberOfPages() {
        return numberOfPages;
    }

    public void setNumberOfPages(int numberOfPages) {
        this.numberOfPages = numberOfPages;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }
}
```

**`Registry` class**

```
package com.levent.prototype;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Registry {

    public static enum TYPE {
        MOVIE,
        BOOK
    }

    private static Registry instance = null;    // lazy loading
    private Map<TYPE, Item> objectMap = null;

    private Registry() {
        // using synchronized only for once so 
        // there will be no performance issues
        // regarding usage of synchronized
        // but not sure if necessity is a MUST ?
        synchronized(Registry.class) {
            objectMap = new HashMap<TYPE, Item>();
            loadItemPrototypes();
        }
    }

    public static Registry getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) {
            // using synchronized only if instance is null
            synchronized(Registry.class) {
                if(instance == null) {
                    instance = new Registry();
                }
            }
        }

        return instance;
    }

    // load object prototypes to map
    private void loadItemPrototypes() {
        Movie movie = new Movie(1, "Default Movie", Item.ItemStatus.AVAILABLE, 86, "John Doe" );
        objectMap.put(TYPE.MOVIE, movie);

        Book book = new Book(1, "Default Book", Item.ItemStatus.AVAILABLE, 342, "J. Random Hacker" );
        objectMap.put(TYPE.BOOK, book);
    }

    // fetches the type from prototype map and returns a clone
    // of the item prototype
    public Item createItem(TYPE type) {
        Item item = null;

        try {
            item = (Item)(objectMap.get(type)).clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            System.out.println("Registry::createItem()::Error on type: " + type);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return item;
    }

}
```

**`Demo` code**

```
package com.levent.prototype;

public class SingletonPrototypeDemo {

    static final int ITEM_SIZE = 6;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Registry registry = Registry.getInstance(); // init

        Item items[] = new Item[ITEM_SIZE];

        initItems(registry, items);

        // Assign some valus to the clones

        // Movies
        ((Movie) items[1]).setDirector("Adam K. Foo");
        ((Movie) items[2]).setDirector("Zac Mac Kracker");
        ((Movie) items[1]).setDuration(92);
        ((Movie) items[2]).setDuration(66);
        items[1].setItemStatus(Item.ItemStatus.SOLD);
        items[2].setItemStatus(Item.ItemStatus.SOLD);
        items[1].setItemTitle("The Story Of A Man Who Lives Silly");
        items[2].setItemTitle("My Teacher And Her Stupid Green Martian Lover");
        items[1].setItemId(2);
        items[2].setItemId(3);

        // Books
        ((Book) items[4]).setAuthor("Michael Z. Dude");
        ((Book) items[5]).setAuthor("Mr. Anonymous");
        ((Book) items[4]).setNumberOfPages(35);
        ((Book) items[5]).setNumberOfPages(983);
        items[4].setItemStatus(Item.ItemStatus.SOLD);
        items[5].setItemStatus(Item.ItemStatus.SOLD);
        items[4].setItemTitle("Dudeism : The New Religion");
        items[5].setItemTitle("A Guide To Everything That You Don't Need To Know");
        items[3].setItemId(4);
        items[4].setItemId(5);
        items[5].setItemId(6);

        // print
        handlePrint(items);
    }

    private static void printItem(Item item) {
        System.out.println("Object         : " + item);
        System.out.println("Item Id        : " + item.getItemId());
        System.out.println("Item Title     : " + item.getItemTitle());
        System.out.println("Item Status    : " + item.getItemStatus());
    }

    private static void initItems(Registry registry, Item items[]) {
        // half of items are movie and the rest are book
        for(int i = 0; i < ITEM_SIZE; i++) {
            if(i < ITEM_SIZE/2)
                items[i] = (Movie) registry.createItem(Registry.TYPE.MOVIE);
            else
                items[i] = (Book)  registry.createItem(Registry.TYPE.BOOK);
        }
    }

    private static void handlePrint(Item items[]) {
        // half of items are movie and the rest are book
        for(int i = 0; i < ITEM_SIZE; i++) {
            if(i < ITEM_SIZE/2)
                printMovie((Movie)items[i]);
            else
                printBook((Book)items[i]);

            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static void printBook(Book book) {
        printItem(book);
        System.out.println("Book Author    : " + book.getAuthor() );
        System.out.println("Book PageNum   : " + book.getNumberOfPages() );
    }

    private static void printMovie(Movie movie) {
        printItem(movie);
        System.out.println("Movie Director : " + movie.getDirector());
        System.out.println("Movie Duration : " + movie.getDuration());
    }

}
```

**Sample output of demo code**

> ```
> Object         : com.levent.prototype.Movie@6d06d69c
> Item Id        : 1
> Item Title     : Default Movie
> Item Status    : AVAILABLE
> Movie Director : John Doe
> Movie Duration : 86
>
> Object         : com.levent.prototype.Movie@7852e922
> Item Id        : 2
> Item Title     : The Story Of A Man Who Lives Silly
> Item Status    : SOLD
> Movie Director : Adam K. Foo
> Movie Duration : 92
>
> Object         : com.levent.prototype.Movie@4e25154f
> Item Id        : 3
> Item Title     : My Teacher And Her Stupid Green Martian Lover
> Item Status    : SOLD
> Movie Director : Zac Mac Kracker
> Movie Duration : 66
>
> Object         : com.levent.prototype.Book@70dea4e
> Item Id        : 4
> Item Title     : Default Book
> Item Status    : AVAILABLE
> Book Author    : J. Random Hacker
> Book PageNum   : 342
>
> Object         : com.levent.prototype.Book@5c647e05
> Item Id        : 5
> Item Title     : Dudeism : The New Religion
> Item Status    : SOLD
> Book Author    : Michael Z. Dude
> Book PageNum   : 35
>
> Object         : com.levent.prototype.Book@33909752
> Item Id        : 6
> Item Title     : A Guide To Everything That You Don't Need To Know
> Item Status    : SOLD
> Book Author    : Mr. Anonymous
> Book PageNum   : 983
> ```

The most of the work is, as I've written above is made on `Registry` class. I've written this whole code to make a demo of a prototype pattern and which is also a singleton pattern. The `Registry` class has a composite structure, is a singleton-prototype.

It is singleton because it has only one instance per JVM. It is also a prototype because it stores object prototypes and creates by cloning them (and notice that base Item class implements the `Cloneable` interface).

Answer (score 1):

#### `Cloneable`

[Some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427883/clone-vs-copy-constructor-which-is-recommended-in-java) [say](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html) `Cloneable` is broken in Java, advocating the use of copy-constructors instead. Perhaps you want to take a look in that direction.

I'm also not sure why you want to `clone()` from the two-element `Map` (which can be implemented as an `EnumMap`) to obtain your array objects.

#### Singletoness

As mentioned [in an earlier answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/126627/24141) to another question of yours, the recommended way is to to use the [`enum` singleton pattern](https://www.google.com/search?q=enum+singleton+java). If you do not want to do so for some reason (e.g. your singleton class must `extend` from an `abstract class`), make the singleton class `final` will prevent users from extending your class and then creating multiple instances of them.

#### Displaying human-readable output

That's what `Object.toString()` is for, it's recommended that you override that instead of having your `printBook(Book)`/`printMovie(Movie)` methods.

Comment: This answer seems very useful (I've also just check your other answer on ConnectionPool code) I've used clone because I want to update my code in future, which will take an unlimited set of Objects and read the type (class name) at runtime. Thank your very much for your useful answer.

Comment: I try to learn the best practice of Java language but because I study design patterns, your comments about the Cloneable interface is important. I've just read Joshua Bloch's view via the link you've provided and because that Java API's Cloneable's clone method is protected, I'll implement the same code/functionality on C++ with a copy constructor or whatever I can do with the language. It's very interesting that even Doug Lea give up on the Cloneable interface. It seems core Java API is written in god-speed and they've missed a very important point.